# latest version of a dependency in maven archetype

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-archetype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maven update dependencies in POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973081/maven-update-dependencies-in-pom)

I'm trying to develop a maven archetype for my future projects. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the latest version of a dependency during project creation.

Comment: Take a look at [versions](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) plugin source code.

Comment: So, you suggest to update to latest release once the project is created. No way to program archetype to get it. Isn't it?