# using LATEST for archetypeVersion always resolves to latest release

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

Generating like this achieves the desired result -- generates using latest snapshot.

```bash
mvn archetype:generate ^
  --show-version ^
  --settings development-maven-settings.xml ^
  -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true ^
  -DarchetypeCatalog=local ^
  -DarchetypeGroupId=dev.aherscu.qa ^
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=qa-testing-archetype ^
  -DarchetypeVersion=0.0.9-SNAPSHOT ^
  -DgroupId=com.acme ^
  -DartifactId=testing ^
  -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ^
  -Dpackage=com.acme.testing
```

The `development-maven-settings.xml` are as follows:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>archetype</id>
          <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Replacing 0.0.9-SNAPSHOT with LATEST always resolves to 0.0.8.
Anyway to make it run with latest snapshot?

Comment: Please do not use `LATEST` as version because it's long time deprecated.. If you are using a SNPSHOT you could change your settings `<updatePolicy> always</updatePolicy>` (see https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#repositories) or you could use `-U` option on command line...

Answer (score -1):

according to this:
[Archetype should always use latest version of dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700158/archetype-should-always-use-latest-version-of-dependency)
it is not possible to get the latest release like this, as the 'latest' will always resolve against your local repo, not the remote repo. So I think if you add the dependency as real `<dependendcy>` with `<version>latest</version>` to your prject and run the 'install' goal, the jar 0.0.9 jar should be installed to your local repo => now your 'latest' should fetch the real latest one.

Comment: "dependency" is irrelevant for generating a project from an archetype.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. You are using DarchetypeCatalog=local therefore your archetype comes from your local repository. As you may not have the current version of the archetype in your local repo it will not get the latest version from somewhere else. The dependency thing was just a suggestion for a workaround. The answer was the first sentence ;)

Comment: but the archetype snapshot is in my local repo, it just takes the release version from central no matter what I tried :(

Comment: huh. interesting. then i guess my answer was indeed not correct.