# Set the version of a dependency from command line

Tags: maven, dependencies, versions-maven-plugin

I would like to set the version of a dependency in a POM from command line. Much like `versions:set` (for the version of the project), but for a specific dependency.

I don't want to craft any XML scanning tool because there are various ways to specify a version and it is hard to handle them all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know your dependency versions are specified in the `dependency` or `dependencyManagement` blog and the version is not a property you can use [use-dep-version](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-dep-version-mojo.html):

```
mvn versions:use-dep-version -Dincludes=io.netty:netty-all -DdepVersion=1.0 -DforceVersion=true
```

However if the version is specified as a property, the `use-dep-version` will not work.

Then you can only use `versions:*-property` commands but for this you need to know the name of the property (which could be achieved by having a naming convention for these properties)

```
mvn versions:set-property -DnewVersion=1.0 -Dproperty=netty-all.version
```

if you need more safety that the version you will use is valid or to avoid downgrades have a look at [update-property](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-property-mojo.html).

If you project is mixed with versions and property versions you could just run both commands and one will change it.

**UPDATE 2024:** Maven goal `use-dep-version` now has attribute [processProperties](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/use-dep-version-mojo.html#processProperties), which if set to `true` will cause also properties to be changed. There is no need for using `versions:*-property` anymore.

Comment: Thank you. It is a shame that this goal is not listed on the versions maven plugin homepage (list of goals).